# Как ответ от сервера поместить в переменную?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Я хочу получить ответ сервера в output. Каким образом это сделать? Я гуглил и ничего не нашёл.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

let output = ''
fetch('https://google.com')
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(text => console.log(text))
```

Comment: Обычно в вашем случае отсылают сюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/ Если что-то будет неясно и захотите разобраться в теме асинхронности основательно, стоит прочитать этот раздел: https://learn.javascript.ru/async

Answer (score 0):

Во первых, не понимаю зачем вам ответ нужно записать именно в переменную аутпут, ибо это нереалистичный сценарий, во вторых лучше сделать так:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

async function func () {
  const response = await fetch('https://google.com').text()
}
```